# prove a function is locally increasing at a point c.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f : [a, b] \rightarrow R$ is continuous, and is differentiable on $(a, b)$. Suppose also that the derivative function $f'$is continuous on $(a, b)$. Let $c \in (a, b)$ with $f (c) > 0$. Then f is locally increasing at c. $f$ is locally increasing at $c$ if there is some $δ > 0$ such that $f$ is increasing on the open interval $(c − δ, c + δ)$.

attempt:
for $x_1 \in (c,c + δ)$ $f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} >0$, so $f(x_1) >f(c)$.
for $x_2 \in (c - δ,c)$ $f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} >0$, so $f(x_2) <f(c)$.
Then I cannot prove why $f(x)$ is increasing in  $(c+δ)$ and $(c − δ)$

Comment: You need to use the intermediate or mean value theorems, or both (I forgot which).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to say that $f'(c)>0$, in this case, since $f'$ is continue, there exists $d>0$ such that for every $x\in (c-d,c+d)$, $f'(x)>0$.

Let $x\in (c-d,c+d)$, $f'(x)>0$ implies there exists $e>0$ sun that for every $y\in (x-e,x+e), {{f(y)-f(x)}\over{y-x}}>0$. If $y>0$, we deduce that $f(y)>f(x)$, if $y<x$, we deduce that $f(y)<f(x)$. So $f$ is locally increasing.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f'(c)>0.$

take $\; \epsilon=\frac{f'(c)}{2}$

$f'$ is continuous at $c \implies$

there exists $\eta>0\;$such that

$$\forall x\in[a,b]$$

$$|x-c|<\eta\implies  0<\frac{f'(c)}{2}<f'(x)$$

on the other hand

$$\forall x,y \in (c-\eta,c+\eta)\;: x<y,$$

by the MVT

$\exists \alpha \in(x,y)\;:\; \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(\alpha)>0$

thus $f$ is increasing in $(c-\eta,c+\eta)$.